# Solve Fantasy Football Optimisation Problem

Tags: python, optimization

I want to solve an optimisation problem using CBC but I have very limited python skills and no real experience of optimisation.

I have a csv file detailing the expected pts of Fantasy Football players for a specific week containing the following columns :

PlayerID, Name, FName, Club, Price, 2_Pts

From this data I want the solver to find the optimal selection of six player's based on 2_Pts within a combined budget of 63.0.

Heres a copy of my rough code, it could be totally terrible. Any help appreciated.

Receiving a value error in relation to the PlayerID field. But overall my code feels scratchy.

```
from pyomo.environ import ConcreteModel, Var, Objective, maximize, Constraint, Set
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import pandas as pd

# Read data from CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('modified_pick6.csv')

# Convert PlayerID column to integers
data['PlayerID'] = data['PlayerID'].astype(int)

# Extract data from the dataframe
player_ids = data['PlayerID']
points = data['2_Pts']
price = data['Price']

# Create a concrete model
model = ConcreteModel()

# Define the set of player IDs
model.player_ids = Set(initialize=player_ids)

print("Min Player ID in CSV:", min(player_ids))
print("Max Player ID in CSV:", max(player_ids))

# Define the decision variables (binary, indicating whether a player is selected or not)
model.x = Var(model.player_ids, within=Binary)

# Define the objective function (maximize total points)
model.obj = Objective(expr=sum(points[i] * model.x[i] for i in model.player_ids), sense=maximize)

# Define the constraint (total price should not exceed 63.0)
model.price_constraint = Constraint(expr=sum(price[i] * model.x[i] for i in model.player_ids) <= 63.0)

# Create a solver instance
solver = SolverFactory('/usr/bin/cbc')

# Solve the optimization problem
result = solver.solve(model)

# Display the results
if result.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal:
    print("Optimal solution found:")
    for i in model.player_ids:
        if model.x[i].value == 1:
            print(f"Player {i}: Points = {points[i]}, Price = {price[i]}")
    print("Total Points:", model.obj())
else:
    print("Solver did not find an optimal solution.")
```

Comment: This problem is essentially a 0-1 knapsack problem. Wikipedia has pseudocode for a fast solution here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0-1_knapsack_problem

Comment: Assuming @NickODell is correct (and I have no reason to doubt them), There are SO posts on the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76380576/0-1-knapsack-problem-with-dynamic-programming and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59014861/0-1-knapsack-problem-simplified-in-python as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74156804/python-pulp-optimization-limiting-total-number-of-one-variable-chosen/74157623#74157623